# Track changes of atributes in instance. Python

Tags: python

I want to implement function which takes as argument any object and trackes changes of value for specific attribute. Than saves old value of attribute in old_name attribute.

For example:

```
class MyObject(object):
     attr_one = None
     attr_two = 1
```

Lets name my magic function `magic_function()`

Sot than i can do like this:

```
obj = MyObject()
obj = magic_function(obj)
obj.attr_one = 'new value'
obj.attr_two = 2
```

and it saves old values so i can get like this

```
print obj.old_attr_one
None
print obj.attr_one 'new value'
```

and

```
print obj.old_attr_two
1
print obj.attr_two
2
```

Something like this.. I wonder how can i do this by not touching the class of instance?

Comment: With one year of experience and 82 questions, I would expect you to format your questions using the correct SO markup by now! :(

Comment: Ok i will do this? But tell me what is SO?

Comment: Pol, I already edited your question and fixed it. You can see the editing history by cliking on the link next to the word "edited". SO is "Stack Overflow".

Comment: cool... Thanks for editing.. never tried this functions.. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a start:

```
class MagicWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, wrapped):
        self._wrapped = wrapped

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self._wrapped, attr)

    def __setattr__(self, attr, val):
        if attr == '_wrapped':
            super(MagicWrapper, self).__setattr__('_wrapped', val)
        else:
            setattr(self._wrapped, 'old_' + attr, getattr(self._wrapped, attr))
            setattr(self._wrapped, attr, val)


class MyObject(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr_one = None
        self.attr_two = 1

obj = MyObject()
obj = MagicWrapper(obj)
obj.attr_one = 'new value'
obj.attr_two = 2

print obj.old_attr_one
print obj.attr_one
print obj.old_attr_two
print obj.attr_two
```

This isn't bullet-proof when you're trying to wrap weird objects (very little in Python is), but it should work for "normal" classes. You could write a lot more code to get a little bit closer to fully cloning the behaviour of the wrapped object, but it's probably impossible to do perfectly. The main thing to be aware of here is that many special methods will not be redirected to the wrapped object.

If you want to do this without wrapping `obj` in some way, it's going to get messy. Here's an option:

```
def add_old_setattr_to_class(cls):
    def __setattr__(self, attr, val):
        super_setattr = super(self.__class__, self).__setattr__
        if attr.startswith('old_'):
            super_setattr(attr, val)
        else:
            super_setattr('old_' + attr, getattr(self, attr))
            super_setattr(attr, val)
    cls.__setattr__ = __setattr__


class MyObject(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr_one = None
        self.attr_two = 1

obj = MyObject()
add_old_setattr_to_class(obj.__class__)
obj.attr_one = 'new value'
obj.attr_two = 2

print obj.old_attr_one
print obj.attr_one
print obj.old_attr_two
print obj.attr_two
```

Note that this is extremely invasive if you're using it on externally provided objects. It globally modifies the *class* of the object you're applying the magic to, not just that one instance. This is because like several other special methods, `__setattr__` is not looked up in the instance's attribute dictionary; the lookup skips straight to the class, so there's no way to just override `__setattr__` on the instance. I would characterise this sort of code as a bizarre hack if I encountered it in the wild (it's "nifty cleverness" if I write it myself, of course ;) ).

This version may or may not play nicely with objects that already play tricks with `__setattr__` and `__getattr__`/`__getattribute__`. If you end up modifying the same class several times, I think this still works, but you end up with an ever-increasing number of wrapped `__setattr__` definitions. You should probably try to avoid that; maybe by setting a "secret flag" on the class and checking for it in `add_old_setattr_to_class` before modifying `cls`. You should probably also use a more-unlikely prefix than just `old_`, since you're essentially trying to create a whole separate namespace.

Comment: You could make `obj.old.attr_one` work too, that's a bit more reusable.

Comment: I deleted my answer as this is substantially the code I was going to add to it but it was posted first! +1!

Comment: But I dont want the new object to be the instance of MagicWrapper. I want it to be the instance of MyObject (((

Comment: @Pol: I've edited my answer to try to do this by modifying MyObject (actually its class), and show why I would normally not take that approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can substitute all attributes with custom properties at runtime. What are you trying to achieve though? Maybe migrating to completely immutable types would be a better choice?

Comment: Does not matter for me... Just want to achieve what i wrote. And see hov the code looks like.. Or maybe you have something similar written already?