# Creating a wrapper class that it is convenient to use

Tags: python, wrapper

In order to keep track of both the current and the previous value of certain variables that are continually updated inside of a loop, I created a wrapper class that automatically stores the old value inside of it when it is updated:

```python
class Updatable:
    def __init__(self, value=None, prev_value=None):
        # Initial conditions
        self._value = value
        self._prev_value = prev_value

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value

    @property
    def prev_value(self):
        return self._prev_value

    def update(self, new_value):
        self._prev_value = self._value
        self._value = new_value

    def has_value(self):
        return self._value is not None

    def has_prev_value(self):
        return self._prev_value is not None
```

However, in order for it to work more like a normal variable, I want all the ordinary operators to work as expected (except assignment, which cannot be overloaded in Python), so I have defined many of the special methods that a class can have:

```python
    # Object representation
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._value)

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self._value)

    # Iteration
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._value)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._value[key]

    def __reversed__(self):
        return reversed(self._value)

    # Arithmetic operations
    def __add__(self, other):
        return self._value + other

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return self._value - other

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return self._value * other

    def __matmul__(self, other):
        return self._value @ other

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        return self._value / other

    def __floordiv__(self, other):
        return self._value // other

    def __mod__(self, other):
        return self._value % other

    def __divmod__(self, other):
        return divmod(self._value, other)

    def __pow__(self, other, *args):
        return pow(self._value, other, *args)

    def __lshift__(self, other):
        return self._value << other

    def __rshift__(self, other):
        return self._value >> other

    def __and__(self, other):
        return self._value & other

    def __xor__(self, other):
        return self._value ^ other

    def __or__(self, other):
        return self._value | other

    # Comparison operators
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self._value == other

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return self._value != other

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self._value < other

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self._value > other

    def __le__(self, other):
        return self._value <= other

    def __ge__(self, other):
        return self._value >= other
```

While this may seem like a lot of special methods, it is still far from [all special methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names), and supporting all of them would mean even more boiler plate code than what I already have.

Furthermore, defining these special methods doesn't allow me to use an instance as the second operand in a binary operation. For example, while the code

```python
a = Updatable(2)
a + 3
```

works, the code

```python
a = Updatable(2)
3 + a
```

results in the error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Updatable'`, which is undesirable if it is going to be convenient to use.

Is there some other approach to creating a wrapper class that is (almost) as convenient to use as using the datatype it is wrapping directly (neglecting the fact that when using the naked datatype, you won't have access to the previous value unless you store it explicitly)?

Comment: For `3 + a` to work, you might need to define [`__radd__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__). Yes, that's a lot of boilerplate code. Now, do you really need all of these methods?

Comment: If you know the expected type of `_value` variable, just inherit from built in type, eg. `class Updatable(int): (...)`

Comment: I'd encourage the poster to consider telling us what the real problem is (unless this is purely an intellectual exercise). I suspect it may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @KWierzbicki the problem with inheriting from `int` or similar objects is that methods inherited from `int` will return `int` results, losing the desired cacheing behaviour.

Comment: Possibly related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727491/track-changes-of-atributes-in-instance-python

Comment: @holdenweb The real problem: I loop through measurements in time series data, check for extreme values in first and second time derivatives, and do linear interpolation between values in adjacent time steps. So I need to keep track of the previous values of the variables I'm working with.

Comment: Consider using pandas and/or numpy.... pandas work with time series data and do interpolation.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye I think you can, but you'll should create a new question with sample data and expected output, tagged with pandas.

Comment: @ScottBoston I'm already working with Pandas. I only need to interpolate some of the values, and only between a small number of all adjacent pairs of time steps, in order to get sub-time step accuracy. Can I do that in Pandas?

Comment: Would it be possible to simply keep two generations of the Pandas dataframe? It would be easy to use subtraction between the dataframes to get a matrix of the difference at each position. Just a thought. I don't think you need this level of complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your class defination:

```
# Arithmetic operations
def __radd__(self, other):
    return other + self._value

def __add__(self, other):
    return self._value + other
```

and then

```
a = Updatable(2)
3 + a
```

Output:

```
5
```

With the original function defination `__add__`:

```
a = Updatable(2)
a + 3
```

Output:

```
5
```

Comment: Nice, although I would change the order of the operands in the `+` operation, otherwise it will fail for datatypes with [noncommutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) plus operators, such as `str`.

Comment: Could you switch the order of the operands in the `+` operation in your answer, please?